# Strange Short Story About A Programmer Who Programs all The Angels

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

There's a horror/science-fiction short story about a programmer or scientist who programs all the angels from like the Old Testament or something. His reasoning is that it provides some kind of relatively compact microcosm to embed agents (i.e. his angels). I don't remember the end, and I can't find this story, but I always meant to read it again. Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very likely Robert Silverberg's 1983 story "[Basileus](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?73377)", available through the Baen Free Library [here](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781625791375/9781625791375___1.htm).

Summary from [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Z11BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=short%20story%20programmer%20angels&source=bl&ots=-63hRWTZze&sig=m2AHKj0vrdlyTCEQF42pLQONlZE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFo4TQwqPVAhXIVj4KHXHnBucQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=short%20story%20programmer%20angels&f=false):

> "Basileus" also places nuclear war in a religious context, describing a computer programmer for the Department of Defense named Cunningham who spends his spare time designing computer simulations of angels.

Comment: Found by searching for *short story programmer angels*. If this is the correct answer, don't forget to click on the checkmark to accept it.